# If statement only taking into consideration each hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I get my `if statement` to assess an entire period of time, for instance, every second from 06:00:00 to 11:00:00, instead of what it is doing at the moment, wherein it misses times like 06:15:00:

```
if (time == "6am - 11am") {
    if (rideshareTime == "06:00:00" || rideshareTime == "07:00:00" || rideshareTime == "07:00:00" || rideshareTime == "08:00:00" || rideshareTime == "09:00:00" || rideshareTime == "10:00:00" || rideshareTime == "11:00:00") {
        if (luggageSpace == "Yes") {
            if (rideshareSeats >= seatsAvailable && luggageSpace == rideshareLuggage && womenOnly == rideshareWomen) {
                $obj.closest('.rideshare-item').show();
            }
        } else {
            if (rideshareSeats >= seatsAvailable && womenOnly == rideshareWomen) {
                $obj.closest('.rideshare-item').show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of the same

Comment: Use a `Date` object and compare actual time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a date/time library like momentjs.com and it's `isBetween` method.

You could solve it using the string datatype and it's `substring` method. Although I don't recommend it because strings are not made to operate on dates/time.

```
if (rideshareTime.substring(0,2) == "06" || rideshareTime.substring(0,2) == "07" || rideshareTime.substring(0,2) == "07" || rideshareTime.substring(0,2) == "08" || rideshareTime.substring(0,2) == "09" || rideshareTime.substring(0,2) == "10" || rideshareTime == "11:00:00")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you need values from 06:00:00 to 11:00:00, you can either use regex to test the string or parse it to numbers and test using < or >.

For the first approach, the string format is either 0[6-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] or 10:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] or 11:00:00 (Assuming hours:minutes:seconds).

*Note* : The above representations are **not** regex expressions, and I have written to convey the idea. You can convert them to valid regex expressions.

Or

Parse the string into three numbers - hours, minutes and seconds and test it i.e.

```
total_seconds = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds 
if(total_seconds >= 6*3600 && total_seconds <= 11*3600)
    ...do my job....
```

Also, you can look into third party libraries to deal with more time formats and which will involve less work.

Answer (score 2):

If your rideshareTime is a string you can use the Regex `/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/g`

```
if (time.match(/[0-9]+am:[0-9]+pm/g).length) {
    if (rideshareTime.match(/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/g).length && _isRideShareTimeValid(rideshareTime)) {
        if (luggageSpace == "Yes") {
            if (rideshareSeats >= seatsAvailable && luggageSpace == rideshareLuggage && womenOnly == rideshareWomen) {
                $obj.closest('.rideshare-item').show();
            }
        } else {
            if (rideshareSeats >= seatsAvailable && womenOnly == rideshareWomen) {
                $obj.closest('.rideshare-item').show();
            }
        }
    }
}


_isRideShareTimeValid(time){
  time = time.replace(':','');
  timeNumbers = time.split('').map(function(a){ return parseInt(a);});
  return time.length >= 3 && time.length <= 6 && timeNumbers.every(function(p){ p!=NaN});
}
```

Comment: How would this work for other times i.e. 11am - 2pm (11:00:00-14:00:00) and 2pm - 5pm (14:00:00-17:00:00)?

Comment: I didnt understand, can you clarify what is the format of your `rideshareTime` variable?  also you can use `time.match(/[0-9]+am[0-9]+pm/g).length > 0`

Comment: Wouldn't this match things like 0:0:0 or 12345:12345:12345, that are invalid? Maybe it would be better with something like `^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yes it would, I supposed that the strings are correct.

Comment: The format is always the same, it doesn't change i.e. 16:00:00, 17:00:00. It is only the range that varies. The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/HXSARekw

Comment: @methuselah @AlvaroMontoro I updated my answer checking the time, and with a helper function to test if `rideshareTime` is a "valid" time.